# Does the "My Little Pony" franchise belong in SF&F?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are our boundaries?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1028/what-are-our-boundaries)

**Context**: I know it's hard to decide what is and what isn't Science Fiction or Fantasy. This is a classic discussion that goes well beyond the history of SE or even the internet. However, for scifi.SE, if a line isn't drawn this is just a "Movies & TV shows" website.

Now, correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't [My Little Pony](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15815/what-does-derpys-cutie-mark-mean) a kids cartoon with little relationship to the Fantasy genre and none to SF? I'm obviously not the target demographic for this show and therefore not familiar with it, so I might be wrong, but is there enough fantasy content in MLP to qualify for this site? [By reading Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendship_Is_Magic), I see the show "still incorporates episodic creatures intended to be frightening to children, such as dragons and hydras"... but does that qualify as Fantasy? In that case, would almost every Disney cartoon qualify for this website?

Note: I know there is *some* fantasy, which is why I won't argue the case that there is none. But almost every TV show involves some degree of fantasy. Where do we draw the line? Does a line need to be drawn at all?

Comment: Not that we've completely established the boundaries or have a real consensus, but I don't think your question covers any new ground compared to the discussion we had a few months back.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice there was already a discussion about this.