# What just happened to the Teletubbies questions?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question

I mean, I know [my question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2184/are-the-teletubbies-cyborgs) was one of two that just got migrated but there was no explanation or suggestion, it just went.

So I have two questions:

1. Why was it migrated?
2. What about all the other tv and movie questions? Are we going to migrate the Star Wars and Star Trek questions as well?

Update: I managed to get the [original question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8722/are-the-teletubbies-cyborgs?noredirect=1) and found out it was done by @Keen so maybe he can answer?

Comment: The discussion here seems to cover it: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1028/what-are-our-boundaries

Comment: More specifically, [Are children's literature and cartoons for children on-topic?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/683/are-childrens-literature-and-cartoons-for-children-on-topic) is appropriate.

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted? It's a legitimate question about an unresolved issue which I have also recently questioned. It's still not clear what is and what isn't on-topic here!

Comment: @AndresF. Thanks, there are also a few unexplained down votes on the answers as well.

Comment: Downvotes on meta sites don't mean the same thing as on main sites.  Roughly, they mean "I disagree."

Comment: @Ward: what's there to disagree with?! I'm not making a suggestion, I'm asking what happened.

Comment: Your question sounds like you don't think it should've been migrated.  Even if that's not what you meant or if there's another reason people are downvoting, don't worry about it because downvotes here don't mean anything on the main site.

Comment: @Ward: thx, and you're right, I don't think it should have been migrated. I think we are being inconsistent, especially since one of the questions was around here for months.

Comment: I did not downvote your question (I generally don't downvote meta questions), but I suspect you may have gotten downvotes for suggesting that every other question that deals with a tv show and/or movie should be migrated as well.

Comment: @Beofett: **thank you**. That, together with the upvotes on your comment, is an answer to the question on the downvotes I had. The point I was trying to make is **where do you draw the line?** I think we're getting closer but I don't think we've got a perfect solution yet (if that is even possible).

Comment: I plan on watching an episode or two of Teletubbies tonight before posting a response, but my understanding was that the show was pretty superficial, given its pre-school target audience.  The two Teletubbies questions were flagged, and the Movies&TV.SE mods were happy to have them.  Given the lack of a substantial sci-fi or fantasy world in the show, I figured it was more appropriate for them to reside there, an option that wasn't present when you asked your question, as Movies.SE didn't have TV as part of its scope.

Comment: @Keen: thanks for replying. But [to quote Gilles](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/337/are-works-that-arent-sf-per-se-but-have-occasional-sfnal-elements-on-topic-e/344#344), *"If the question is specifically about an sf-nal element, even if it's only a minor part of the work, it's on-topic."* So, I suggest the questions are on topic (cyborgs are part of sci-fi) and would really like consistency. But I'm not going to go on about this... life's too short! :)

Comment: It seems to me that many of the points raised here assert, *Teletubbies is not Sci-fi*. Agreed. However, my question was certainly Sci-Fi in nature: are they **cyborgs**?

Comment: @Wikis Asking if Mary Poppins is a Timelord doesn't mean her movie is sci-fi.  Her ability to fly via umbrella, cast spells on toys that have been left out, and using a bag of holding makes her fantasy, maybe.  Is there some actual sci-fi/fantasy to the Teletubbies world?

Comment: @Keen, again, my thanks for your response. Apart from [the magic bag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teletubbies#Characters), [the robot Noo-Noo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teletubbies#Characters), the magic (or Sci-Fi) of their communication with the outside world and **the inbuilt televisions in their bodies**, nothing. :)

Comment: @Wikis - Agreed. Questions about the sci-fi aspects of a non-sci-fi show are definitely on topic.

Comment: @Richard: thanks, but apparently we are in the minority.

Comment: @Wikis - I find it intriguing that my stack answers are so popular, while my meta answers generally sleep with the fishes.

Comment: @Richard, I don't hang around on meta long enough to know much about your answers but your main site answers are completely awesome! You must have read the entire internet or something...

Comment: @Wikis - Some of them could definitely do with some work. I don't want to swamp the "recent" list with a mass of revisions though.

Answer (score 2):

Shamelessly borrowing from [Mark Beadles' answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1791/1359) on another question:

While the show might have a cult following outside its intended age group, the universe setting is barely developed and highly repetitive.

One might say it has "fantasy" elements, but only in the sense that fantasy can mean "imagination". The show has imagination, but not speculation.

[Plot elements are primitive to the point of non-existence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Teletubbies_episodes_and_videos).

Comment: I agree the Teletubbies match this criteria and should be excluded (thank god! we can agree on something). Can you tell me if you think MLP escapes it, and if so, how? With evidence, please :)

Comment: while you are at it, can you tell me whether this set of rules discriminates against the Smurfs? The Smurfs have plots, are some sort of fantasy goblins/elfs, and have an evil warlock as their enemy. Yet someone else (not you) argued they are off-topic here.

Comment: I do think MLP does not fit this description (nor, for that matter, the Smurfs). Evidence: [Plot summary for Episode 2 of Teletubbies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Teletubbies_episodes_and_videos): "The Teletubbies jump around and watch a movie about a kid and his pig Winnie."

Comment: [Plot summary for Episode 2 of Friendship is Magic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_My_Little_Pony:_Friendship_Is_Magic_episodes): "After Nightmare Moon's prevail of eternal night, Twilight Sparkle, with the addition of her new friends, sets out to find the Elements of Harmony in order to defeat Nightmare Moon. Twilight also learns an important message of friendship in the process."

The Smurfs actually has several movies, comics, and specials, so presumably there's more plot than "the smurfs jump around and watch a movie".

Comment: Good explanation! I think it should be part of your answer.

Comment: Fair enough. Edited to include the Teletubbies episode guide (remind me to make sure my kid *never* watches this!).

Comment: Have you no shame, Beofett!?! Oh, wait, I see you said you don't. Carry on then.

Answer (score -1):

This older [question on "what are the boundaries of scifi.se"](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1028/what-are-our-boundaries) got a lot of activity yesterday, discussing what makes My Little Pony Friendship is Magic on-topic vs. other kid's shows that might or might not be.  As you can see, there is some sentiment that kid's shows aren't on topic and FIM may be an exception.

In any case, with the topic fresh in peoples' minds, both Teletubbies questions were probably flagged as being off-topic and Keen responded to those.

Comment: The age range doesn't have anything to do with the general consensus of that discussion. I don't think anyone is seriously arguing that an intended audience makes something scifi/fantasy.

Comment: ??I'm not sure what the comment has to do with my answer... I didn't say anything about "age range"

Comment: @Ward Your answer mentions the age range explicitly with: `kid's shows aren't on topic`.

Answer (score -2):

Short answer; We must accept the Teletubbies if and only if we accept My Little Pony.

I don't lean either way, but the community appears to accept MLP, so the answer is, Teletubbies should stay here, too.

Comment: I'd rather reject both, but if MLP stays, then the Teletubbies must stay as well. And also the Smurfs, I find [this justification of why they shouldn't](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/1074/770) rather bizarre. It doesn't get _any more fantastical_ than the Smurfs; I'd _love_ to see an explanation that rejects the Smurfs but accepts My Little Pony!

Comment: [This answer](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/1791/1359) has a great explanation for why Teletubbies does not qualify as on topic. The whole "if *a* is accepted, then *b* needs to be accepted" is not really valid when the difference between *a* and *b* is so vast.

Comment: This is a [fallacy of false cause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy#Fallacy_of_false_cause). You're asserting that there is no causation for MLP being on topic and Teletubbies being off.

Comment: @Beofett (I'm not stalking you, I swear :P) Unfortunately, I don't agree with the answer you quoted; or rather, I disagree it successfully discriminates between TT and MLP. MLP is a show, with kid's themes, aimed at kids, where the "fantastical" element is probably just typical of cartoons for kids. Whether it has some adult fan base or not is as irrelevant as for the TT (IMO)

Comment: @AndresF. My last *thwap* on the corpse of this equine: the fan base quite explicitly called out as irrelevant in the answer I quoted, so I'm not sure which answer you were reading. If you disagree, feel free to downvote my answer on this question above.