# Specific question about what Children's Literature is on topic (Cloudy with a Chance of Meatballs)

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13823/what-powers-the-fldsmdfr-when-its-in-the-sky) (and its [related tag](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cloudy-with-meatballs)) is about [*Cloudy with a Chance of Meatballs*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloudy_with_a_Chance_of_Meatballs) which Wikipedia classifies as a children's picture book (and a related movie). Some books and movies "intended for children" are of course indisputable classics of science fiction (works by Tolkien, Lewis, Baum, L'Engle...) and are obviously on-topic here.

I have seen the related meta question about whether [children's literature and cartoons for children are on-topic](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/683/are-childrens-literature-and-cartoons-for-children-on-topic).  The answer there was "would a serious fan of the science fiction or fantasy genres consider spending any amount of effort digging into the details [the work]? If the answer is yes, it's on-topic. If the answer is no, it's off-topic."

The questioner, when I asked about this, responded "It's certainly fiction based on speculative science. Wildly speculative, but still science based."  So is *Cloudy with a Chance of Meatballs* something that is valuable to have on a site for serious fans of science fiction or fantasy?

Comment: Seems to me that most of these "Is this scifi/fantasy" questions come down to one thing: whether those voting like the story. I don't get the Cloudy w/ Meatballs thing, but I do get the Beauty and the Beast questions that are also up. Seems too much a matter of personal opinion as to what's on topic/off when we get into pedantry, IMHO.

Comment: @GabeWillard  Ouch! I certainly wasn't trying to be pedantic. I just think that SE works best when questions are asked in the most appropriate place.

Comment: I didn't intend that as a personal dig; apologies if that's how it sounded. I agree that questions should be asked in the right place, I just think that in the realm of scifi/fantasy, we should be a little hesitant to discount something. I will admit, I'd never call CwM scifi, but in the similar case of Beauty and the Beast, I totally agree that that's fantasy. I'm just an advocate of caution before migration/closing.

Comment: I agree with you on both, which is why I asked here :)

Answer (score 5):

We (the Science Fiction and Fantasy community) have always had a slightly uneasy relationship with children's literature, but so far had a slight preference for allowing it. A propos of another borderline subject (technothrillers), I proposed some [guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337/are-works-that-arent-sf-per-se-but-have-occasional-sfnal-elements-on-topic-e/344#344) which seem to have been well-received and include:

> If the question is specifically about an sf-nal element, even if it's only a minor part of the work, it's on-topic.

As this specific question concerns an sf-nal element, it would therefore be on-topic.

While [Mark Trapp's argument](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/683/are-childrens-literature-and-cartoons-for-children-on-topic/685#685)

> I think the line is pretty straightforward: would a serious fan of the science fiction or fantasy genres consider spending any amount of effort digging into the details of a children's cartoon?

was intended as exclusive, it can be read in an inclusive way. Yes, there are adult fans of Disney movies or Dr Seuss, so why not *Tiny Toons* or *Cloudy with a Chance of Meatballs*?

Comment: Thanks. The first guideline you give certainly makes sense, and is applicable to this case. The problem I have with Mark Trapp's argument is this: if it were the only guideline, then it would lead to any sort of *Tiny Toons* question being on topic. There is nothing wrong with *Tiny Toons*, of course, but it's not clear to me that a person looking for answers about that show should expect a "Science Fiction and Fantasy" site to be the right place. But your first guideline does draw the line clearly - if it's a SF *element* it's on topic, and I'm good with that.

Comment: In the case of *Tiny Toons* http://movies.stackexchange.com/ would be the appropriate site, imo, within the scope of their faq.