# Is Ducktales on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is the Disney TV and comic series Ducktales on topic?

My question [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/174146/how-can-scrooge-mcduck-dive-into-money-without-hurting-himself) was [closed due to being about anthromorphic animals](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5119/31936).

However I strongly feel that Ducktales is far more than anthromorphic animals. It regularly includes demons, curses and ancient cities, and one of the main charicters, Magica De Spell, is a witch. Thus, it should be on topic here.

So, is Ducktales on topic?

Comment: Not to mention the racecars, lasers, and aeroplanes.

Comment: Rewriting history is so *passé*. Can't we get some original sci-fi in here?

Comment: @fluffy I don't know how you remember all that. For me, looking back, it's a duck-blur.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As base instinct I would say yes (having watched the show growing up... Let's just take a look at the theme song (I could have recited it for you, but you can't hear me through typing).

**Things I see in the trailer include: knights, dragons, witches, mummies, robots, space travel...**

All of this seems like it confirms my hunch of:

## YES, Ducktales* is on-topic!

<sub>*This would include the 1987 and 2017 series</sub>

Comment: SO can u vote to reopen?

Comment: @TheAsh I have already. I must admit I closed it too quickly (I would have originally gone with scientific "explanations", but your self-answer show it was answered in-universe).

Comment: Updated theme song: https://youtu.be/v4br44OK_d8

Comment: @TheAsh Oh no... a reboot??? I will have to investigate! If it is anything like the other reboots I have been watching with my kids, it will be not to my expectations....

Comment: so far pleasantly surprised... And they're finally going to investigate Huey Dewey and Louies mother (Della)!

Comment: Knights, mummies and robots make something SFF? That's funny since we have all of those in our past and present, hardly seems like something Science Fictional or Fantastical

Comment: @Edlothiad Fair enough. How about the ray guns, force fields, dragons, aliens, submarines and spaceships without protection from the water and vacuum, or coin tsunamis?

Comment: Sure, those are SFF-nal. I'm just saying, although this show has SFF-nal elements, yet the premise isn't really an SFF show, but maybe I'm wrong. I just think it should be treated how we treat shows with SFF-nal elements but aren't entirely based on SFF (note: anthro-animals are not considered Fantasy on this site.) and only allow questions based on the SFF-nal elements of the content. But if the community agrees with asking whatever then we'll ask whatever.

Comment: @Edlothiad It makes me wonder if familiar with fantasy tropes or not when you make comments like this. I wonder what your thoughts on Indiana Jones are.....

Comment: Your comments make me wonder if familiar with any of our meta policies or discussions. Spaceships -/= sci-fi. Knights =/= Fantasy. Dragons, Rayguns, aliens is more like it. Either way, another user has mad it clear that there are SFF-nal elements in the show.

Comment: @Edlothiad It just show that you did not take in the full context of my answer and are trying to be combative on purpose.

Comment: No I'm trying to force consistency amongst our policies. But since you seem to be unfamiliar with them, that went unbeknownst to you