# Are the Donald Duck comics on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

We have already determined that Duck Tales is [on topic](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11519/is-ducktales-on-topic).

Is Donald Duck on topic? There was already 1 question on the Duck universe, [How wealthy is Uncle Scrooge in the Don Rosa/Carl Barks universe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52872/how-wealthy-is-uncle-scrooge-in-the-don-rosa-carl-barks-universe), but after I created my second question, [What was Scrooge McDuck protected against because of his years of swimming in his money?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/174296/what-was-scrooge-mcduck-protected-against-because-of-his-years-of-swimming-in-hi#174296), a user recommended I make a meta about it to establish a rule on it.

Comment: What kind of Mickey Mouse question is this? Er, wait...

Comment: @Machavity - Are you saying that it Disney belong here?

Comment: @Valorum took me a second, but that is great.

Comment: @Valorum I know i'm reeaaaally late to the party, but could you please explain the word joke to a non English speaker ? ^^'

Comment: @Neyt - It's a play on "does not" in colloquial English. For example you might say that *"He diz nay know what he's talking about."*

Comment: @Neyt - The same humour is at work when you talk about a wooden car with wooden wheels and a wooden engine **that wooden go**. (Wouldn't go)

Comment: @Valorum I should have catch that ^^ Thank you :)

Comment: @Neyt - Now you understand it, I expect (nay, demand) that you use this joke at some point at the first available opportunity

Comment: @Valorum sir, yes sir ! o7 (I tried to find a joke to put in this comment but it Disney came out as planned...)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Yes, and this goes for all the [Disney comics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disney_comics)

<sup>With a small exception at the bottom. And tagging guidance</sup>

The comics are clearly considered on topic as we already have one [well received](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52872/how-wealthy-is-uncle-scrooge-in-the-don-rosa-carl-barks-universe) and one [positively received](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/138894/burbank-reference-in-donald-duck-comics) question on the topic. We even have a [well received](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24077/how-does-mickey-mouses-upslide-work) question on Mickey Mouse's comic adventures.

Well now that we've determined they were accepted in the past, lets compare them against some policies.

---

#### Anthropomorphic animals does not a fantasy make

The Donald Duck adventures seem to clearly break our requirement for what make something on-topic. Considering that although they are anthropomorphic animals, the adventures and themes seem to branch past our every day world into the Science Fictional and Fantastical world. That ticks the box set in [this meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337/are-works-that-arent-sf-per-se-but-have-occasional-sfnal-elements-on-topic-e)

This however fails Valorum's test for talking animals.

> That said, we would consider talking animals to be part of a fantasy if:
>
> - They had been uplifted in some way (either by technology or magic)
> - Their speaking was somehow fantastical to the other characters.
>   <sub>[Meta answer by Valorum](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5119/68872)</sub>

However, while Donald Duck and co's speaking is not "*somehow fantastical to the other characters*", the adventures they carry out overrules this meta.

Another meta discussing children's literature has most of it deemed off-topic unless some invented creature and creative fantasy exists.

> As far as the other concern that will no doubt be raised, of comic-themed cartoons, I think those should be allowed, for now. It's not the best fit, but as almost all comic book heros [sic] are either mutants, genetically engineered, aliens, robots, or people with some futuristic technology, all of which would easily be covered in this site, I say it's on topic
> <sub>[Meta answer by Pearson](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/684/68872)</sub>

There are other characters and events in the series which fit the requirements laid out in the snippet above. With truly fantastical acts and such occurring (such as swimming through gold coins, etc.)

---

All that being said. The Donald Duck comics seem to be clearly on-topic. As for the rest of the Disney comics, some of the earlier ones may be less on-topic than others.

So as a final conclusion, as long as the questions asked are about Science fictional or fantastical elements portrayed in the comics, they're on topic.

For a few examples our recent questions would be deemed on topic, however asking "What model is Donald's house boat base on?" Would be off-topic and closed as such.

---

#### Tagging

I suggest we use a general universe tag for these, my recommendation would be [disney](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disney) (which already exists), we should then have [disney-comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disney-comics) on all the comics specific questions, further down from that the relevant character starring in the comic in question should be added. E.g. in the case of the question [donald-duck](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/donald-duck)

Answer (score 4):

## Yes

It's pretty firmly established that this is a fantasy universe, complete with magic.

Just ask this fine duck:

[image: Magica De Spell]

...who is a known witch, known for stealing coins and turning people into paper. The rest of the series is also not exactly well known for staying with the bounds of reality, so... I suppose that's a yes.

Really, the existence of magic in the universe is what I'd say confirms it. Talking animals, such as ducks, are not enough to make something science fiction/fantasy... but when you throw *magic* into the equation, now that's a different story.

Comment: Wait, so one instance of magic suddenly bring a universe into scope?   Like any eighties sitcom that jumps the shark and then has something supernatural in a late-season episode?   The bar should be higher.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Duck Tails has always had magical, mystical, and science-fiction elements

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd, okay, but Donald Duck comics in general?

Comment: @ThePopMachine That part I'm not sure of. I know Donald and his nephews do have some pretty crazy adventures, but how much or how many of them are based not in reality could be an argument. I can see it being a case-by-case kinda thing.

Comment: As well as hard science fiction, e.g., the famous story where Donald invents Duckmite and uses it to fuel his rocket to the moon.

Comment: Duck Tails  is full SFF but other Donald duck stuff is not

Comment: http://www.cracked.com/article_19021_5-amazing-things-invented-by-donald-duck-seriously.html

Comment: @ThePopMachine yes, by way of the Nolanverse rule. There's zero inherently fantasy elements of the Nolan Batman films, but they're on topic because they're part of the DC universe which is on-topic. By the same logic, Donald Duck is part of the Disney fantasy universe, which is on topic.