# Is Bugs Bunny (as a whole) on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Pretty much the same question than [Are the Donald Duck comics on-topic?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11528/), although different characters, as so far, it doesn't seem we discussed either [Bugs Bunny](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=bugs%20bunny) or the [Looney Tunes](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=looney%20tunes) on Meta. We have three [looney-tunes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/looney-tunes) questions but two are about Marvin (deffo on-topic), another is [Bugs Bunny picture book involving a machine that creates carrots](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/204829/), which motivated this Meta post.

Per [Are anthropomorphic animals by themselves enough to deem a work fantasy?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5117/):

> **That said, we would consider talking animals to be part of a fantasy if:**
>
> - They had been **uplifted** in some way (either by technology or magic)
> - Their speaking was **somehow fantastical** to the other characters.

I am no expert on Bugs Bunny, but I don't think he fits either of those? As for "tackling the SFF elements in those", we have [three Bugs Bunny questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=bugs%20bunny%20is%3Aq):

- [Novel about Bugs Bunny being tricked by a wealthy man to loot some snowy building](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/135054) which already spawned some heat in the comments. One side argues anvils fall from the skies, the other argues that the anvils are just generic kids cartoon weirdness, not really on-topic.
- [Bugs Bunny picture book involving a machine that creates carrots](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/204829/) same arguments could probably go on for a new round.
- [1990s cartoon movie - Bugs Bunny anti-drugs](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/140219/) video is unavailable but this looks just like an anti-drug PSA? Is that really on-topic?

**TL;DR:**

- what to do with those? Leave them all open? Close some?
- in the future, are all Bugs Bunny stories on-topic the way Donald Duck was?

Comment: As a whole? Probably not from my limited understanding but SFF aspects are yes and from the examples I imagine a machine that can turn junk into carrots is pretty damn like fantasy to me.

Comment: And _Space Jam_ would indicate Looney Tunes is in a sort of parallel world to ours which would make it more on topic I think.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Space Jam aye, but the assumption from the Donald Duck Meta (well, not the meta so much, but rather the "constated policy") is that _everything_ is on-topic even if it's IDing a comic where he looses against a chess player/burns his house/etc. Do we want the same for Bugs?

Answer (score 11):

## Yes, and the same goes for Looney Tunes as a whole

I won't repeat it all here but essentially the conclusion is the same as in the [Donald Duck](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11528/58193) meta.

So, why should it be on topic?

- It has aliens: Marvin the Martian
- Fantastical devices: Carrot making machine
- Takes place on a different world/universe/thingy: See *Space Jam*
- [Has witches and so magic](https://i.pinimg.com/236x/52/a1/29/52a129a50a9add664d67c3b706fd0fed--vintage-cartoons-classic-cartoons.jpg)

And whilst [anthropomorphic animals don't make something on topic](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5119/58193) as seen in *Space Jam* it is clearly not normal in that world for humans to think animals can talk or in fact that the Looney Tunes actually exist.

---

At the very least questions about the SFF-nal nature of the universe are on topic anyway.

Comment: I don't know, it seems like there might be a conflict of interest here _TheLethalCarrot_.

Comment: @gla3dr Avatar checks out too.

Comment: "At the very least questions about the SFF-nal nature of the universe are on topic anyway." I think that should be key, for Looney Tunes and other shows/comics of that nature, because *their genres were deliberately varied*. They weren't necessarily self-consistent "universes" the way many series are. Some episodes/shows the creators made SF&F-related. Others were send-ups Old West adventures, or take-offs on Robin Hood, and so-on, or just slapstick in more pedestrian contexts.