# Looking for feedback on a Looney Tunes episode identification question closed as off-topic

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

*Note: <s>The question is closed as off-topic and deleted, and I want it to remain that way.</s> I just wanted to ask for feedback on why it was closed, so I can avoid doing the same mistakes again (if possible from the close voters, because only they can definitely tell me what I did wrong).*

---

Around 2 months ago, I asked [this (deleted) episode identification Looney Tunes question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/243293/looney-tunes-episode-in-which-a-bird-walks-and-hops-then-disappears-when-passin), in which I was talking about a scene I remember. (I will gladly post a screenshot if you have less than 10k reputation and still want to see it).

Although I can't even remember from what series I saw it in (it could have been from *The Sylvester & Tweety Mysteries*, as well as from any other series from the Looney Tunes universe), what I did remember was the fact that the bird I was looking for was described as an *almighty bird*. As in, he could perform impossible feat, to some inhuman extent, even for a cartoon world.

Shortly after, the question was closed as off-topic, and one comment (not from a close voter) mentioned there was no Science Fiction element about it. I must admit, that confused me quite a lot on that instant, because I don't often see a bird that can tear a mountain in half (I'm not being sarcastic; I'm serious).

So, after pondering the question for 2 months in my corner, I wanted to better understand.

I remember a meta answer mentioning that ["questions about the SFF-nal nature of the [Looney Tunes] universe are on topic"](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12320/103122). But... is it Sci-fi to have an almighty bird in a cartoon? I mean, it's not like The Mask which happens in a realistic world.

Comment: FWIW I don't think it is off topic, however, this is a common trope in these sorts of cartoons so it is pretty borderline "needs more focus".

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot You mean, since the question is asking about a common cartoon trope (disappearing behind a lamp post), rather than about one of the bird's inhuman feat (beating a T-rex as a bird barely bigger than a child)?

Comment: Yeah, you're asking to identify it based mostly off of the common trope. FWIW I voted to reopen it when it was in the queue before deletion, it's certainly borderline too broad but it's better than a lot of what gets left open and there's enough to make some educated guesses I feel.

Comment: Don't try to understand. The vandals who go around closing perfectly good questions becaus there's no "SF element" are not going to give you a definition of what they think they mean by "SF element".

Comment: user14111 - I don't think it's terribly helpful to describe people who're keenly working to keep the site relevant and topical as "vandals" just because you don't agree with their decisions sometimes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was unaware that this had been closed and have voted to undelete it (and will vote to reopen it when that happens).

- [Looney Tunes is on topic.](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12320/98028)
- I can't see that this is 'too broad'. You're asking us to narrow down an episode from less than a few hundred, where a specific character does something. There can't possibly be more than one (or at best a few) instance/s where this occurs.

---

In this case, I believe that Clara Diaz Sanchez, Organic Marble, DavidW, LogicDictates and Invisible Trihedron have erred and voted something closed that's perfectly on-topic (and potentially answerable) and amflare, Shreedhar and Edlothiad have compounded the error by voting to leave it closed when it re-entered the queue.

Comment: Voted to undelete as well.

Comment: Although the thread didn't serve the purpose I initially created it for, I guess the final outcome turned out better than I was hoping for. Thanks. I mean it. For some reasons, thinking about that question being closed somehow didn't help my mood the last 2 months. I guess not knowing why it was considered off-topic despite being practically sure it should be, made me feel like I really sucked at understanding basic rules.

Comment: @Clockwork - No worries. Hopefully now someone will actually answer it for you. I was planning to put in some legwork over the next few days if it's still un-answered...