# Is Richie Rich on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

[Richie Rich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richie_Rich_(comics)), the star of 50+ comic serials, multiple TV shows (and at least one truly terrible film) is famously the world's richest boy and scion to a vast fortune. But someone merely being *grotesquely wealthy despite having no obvious talent* is hardly the stuff of fantasy, so is he on-topic as a result of any other features of his portrayal, such as the casual acceptance of science fiction or fantasy?

Is the depiction of any SFF content in his properties so infrequent that it's [only on-topic to ask about those very occasional lapses](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337/are-works-that-arent-sf-per-se-but-have-occasional-sfnal-elements-on-topic-e) or is his entire world sufficiently scifi-y/fantastical that [all questions about him are generally on topic](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11519/is-ducktales-on-topic)?

Comment: In the spirit of Be Nice, unnecessary insults aimed at celebrities do not contribute to the site. Thus I have edited it out.

Comment: @Adamant - It was illustrative

Comment: Now I'm feeling guilty, having been the one to **Ask* a Richie Rich question in the first place!

Comment: @Russhiro - I despair of people who're downvoting a time-traveling, ghost-befriending, robot-owning, pirate-alien-fighting trillionaire for being off-topic.

Comment: @Valorum Maybe they are just thinking "give it time; Elon Musk or Bill Gates will get there," and using that to show its _less_ "fictional" than other comic stories, lol.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Richie Rich is on topic here.

*[Richie Rich: The Poor Little Rich Boy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richie_Rich_(comics))* (the 1956 Harvey Comics serial) did *initially* start out as a semi-realistic depiction for the first few tens of comics, but then rapidly descended into fantasy and science fiction with the regular appearance of a range of fantastical inventions.

[image]
<sub><sup>[Richie Rich #25](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richie_Rich_(comics)#Publication_history)</sup></sub>

[image]
<sub><sup>[Richie Rich #28](https://www.comics.org/issue/228612/)</sup></sub>

By the early 1960s, Richie was regularly having adventures with Casper the Friendly Ghost (another of Harvey's stable of comics), culminating in a crossover comic in 1974.

[image]

By 1977 his comic serials included outright scifi like [Richie Rich: Inventions](https://richie-rich.fandom.com/wiki/Richie_Rich_Inventions)

[image]

And [Richie Rich Featuring Irona](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/richie-rich-and-6-irona-the-robot-maid/4000-227046/) in which his robotic maid (first introduced in Richie Rich #100) now played a starring role

[image]

The 1980s cartoon series was even more overtly scifi/fantasy, featuring a regular segment called [Richie Rich and his Zillion-dollar Adventures](https://hanna-barbera.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Richie_Rich_Zillion_Dollar_Adventures_segments). These largely comprised of Richie fighting monsters and aliens.

Comment: I apologize if I created a monster.

Comment: @Spencer - We have a [scope] tag precisely so that we can discuss these sorts of things :-)

Comment: Downvoters, could you provide some reference why you think this wouldn't be suitable for our site?

Comment: The on-topic stuff should be, the non-sff should be. It's set in the real world, asking about the real-world isn't on-topic so neither should it here.

Comment: @Edlothiad - His robot maid is in hundreds of serials and his best friend is a ghost. It's not set in anything even close to the real world.

Comment: Rocky Balboa had a robot maid. Is he on-topic now?

Comment: @Skooba - A) The robot in Rocky was barely science fictional. It rolls into a room, delivers a beverage, then repeats a pre-scripted set of phrases. B) Was Rocky's best friend also a ghost?

Comment: @Valorum In fact yes, Mickey dies and haunts him XD

Comment: I find the downvotes frustrating here. Richie Rich contains deep and recurring elements of both fantasy and science fiction. It's far more 'on topic' than other properties that we wouldn't dream of questioning.

Comment: @Spencer considering I think this whole thread was made in regards to a question _I_ intially asked last week, I think it should be _me_ who apologizes, friend. LMAO.